# NetLogo : what is a good way for Storing link values and deducting the dead link values without calling links more than 1 time?

Tags: netlogo

I am sorry to keep asking about links, but one of the features that I am going to add to my model is considering collective mutual relationship of people of different villages in village's future relationships,

I have a few thousand links and it's not efficient to call links and get their value whenever the village wants to make a decision (the decision is made every 48 ticks at clock 0)

Agents own belongs_to which is one one `"Village1" Village2" Village3" or "Village4"`
Links have a Value of Relationship.

This is the function I used to update links value:

```
to Update_link_Values  [Other_Agent Value]
  if self != Other_Agent
  [  
    ifelse  out-link-neighbor? Other_Agent
      [
        ask out-link-to Other_Agent  
        [ 
          set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value  
          set-List-of-Mutual-Obligations 
        ]   
      ] 
      [
        create-link-to Other_Agent 
        [
          set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value 
          set-List-of-Mutual-Obligations 
        ]   
      ]  
  ]
end
```

if I use following formula to store sum of relationship values for different villages it takes 0.003 MS to calculate all mutual relationship values

```
 if [belongs_to] of end1 = "Village1" and [belongs_to] of end2 = "Village2" 
     [
       set List-of-Mutual-Obligations replace-item 0 List-of-Mutual-Obligations (item 0 List-of-Mutual-Obligations  +  Value-Of-The-Relationship)   
       ]
```

While this one takes 1.002 MS to execute,

```
  if [belongs_to] of end1 = "Village1" and [belongs_to] of end2 = "Village2" 
      [  
        set List-of-Mutual-Obligations replace-item 0 List-of-Mutual-Obligations sum [Value-Of-The-Relationship] of links with [[Belongs_to] of end1 = "Village1" and  [Belongs_to] of end2 = "Village2"]
        ]
```

my problem with first version is that it adds the value of each link to sum of all values of previous links in that group and does not consider if a link is dead or not, but second one is more accurate.

Since Value of relationship is link property I don't want to ask links more than once in the code and I update the sum values whenever a link is being changed or created.

I thought it might be better to update the values every 48 ticks , since many agents might call this function every tick, but for doing that I have to call links and I am not sure which way is better?

**Update:**

I have changed my code so I will calculate the links I need whenever a decision is made:

```
to-report Value-of-Mutual-Obligations [Village1 Village2]
  report sum [Value-Of-The-Relationship] of links with [[Belongs_to] of end1 = Village1 and  [Belongs_to] of end2 = Village2]       
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of thinking of it.

Create a breed for the Villages.

```
breed [ villages village ]
```

Create new link breeds, one for the villages, and one for people. (you can't use the built-in links breed when you have any custom links breed):

```
directed-link-breed [ village-links village-link ]
directed-link-breed [ person-links person-link ]
```

give village-links a variable VALUE-OF-MUTUAL-OBLIGATIONS
give the villages a variable VALUE-OF-SELF-OBLIGATIONS -- this is to handle cases where both persons are from the same village -- sadly, netlogo does not allow self-links.

Create a village turtle for each village. They can be hidden. You can apply the name of the village ("Village 1") to the label of the village.

Link all the villages to each other, in both directions.

A person's belongs-to contains a village turtle.

e.g. to randomly assign a village:

```
set belongs-to one-of villages
```

So, now, rather than having to calculate the value of mutual obligations wholesale, you can alter it directly, as it changes.

Whenever you change the value of a link, you can also change the VOMO variable for the village link. You use the who numbers of the villages to figure out the link ID, or to use the SELF-OBLIGATIONS version in that special case.

```
to update-relationship-value [ #value ] ;; run by the person's LINK
   set value-of-the-relationship value-of-the-relationship + #value
   let from-village [ belongs-to ] of end1
   let to-village   [ belongs-to ] of end2

   ifelse from-village != to-village 
   [ ask village-link ([who] of from-village ) ([who] of to-village)
     [ set value-of-mutual-obligations value-of-mutual-obligations + #value
     ]
   ]
   [ ask from-village ;; update self-obligation value
     [ set value-of-self-obligations value-of-self-obligations + #value
     ]
   ]
end
```

So, you only touch the value of mutual obligations once, when you update the relationship value.

You could probably make this slightly more efficient by extracting the village link update code so that it's run by the turtle, not by the link, so that you don't have the extra "[stuff] of end1" stuff.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, I was thinking of the same, but I was not sure if having new breed will increase the complexity. But your answer is really helpful

Comment: Yes, it depends, sometimes adding a little more structural complexity (like using extra breeds as data structures) decreases the code complexity (like now one doesn't need to use complicated list-based code to store and manipulate the values).